# discord.js Command that gives/removes role from everyone, and only an Admin can use it

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to make a command that gives everyone a role, and only an admin can use it.
I found this piece of code on the internet and I tried to modify it, but nothing is helping me out, and I've been reading the error, and I still get nothing

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === 'grimm!rainbow') {
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'Rainbow')
        if (!role) return message.channel.send(`a Rainbow role was not found, create one and set it on top of all roles for this command to work!`)
        message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => member.addRole(role))
        message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, The Rainbow has been turned on!`)
}});
```

And another thing, I would like it if this command can only be used by an admin, but I've been struggling with code in that range, and I have no clue on how to work it.
If someone could help me out a little bit? and explain what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if user have admin permission you need to using `.hasPermission()` docs here:

```js
if(message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'){
   // Doing Something
}
```

To add roles to all user you need to access guild members cached , doc [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache) and then loop through all members , access their roles and you will have `.add()` for add specific role docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberRoleManager). Similar for remove

```js
message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => member.roles.add(role))
```